# How to use Eclipse for capturing the structure of a java software

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to learn an open source software developed using Java. The software itself is complicated, consisting of multiple packages. I would like to know how to understand the inter-relationships or dependences of these packages under Eclipse developement environment. Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want? The question is vague.  Using Eclipse, you can find references or definitions by highlighting a method, then right clicking and choosing "References", or by pressing F3.

Comment: It could be as simple as looking at the `import`s at the top of any given class file.

Comment: Great question! I always wondered if there are tools around that help to quickly grok the structure of a project. Haven't found any myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visualization of the dependencies will help. A nice free Eclipse plug-in that supports this is Google's [CodePro Analytix](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/codepro/doc/features/dependencies/dependencies.html), acquired from their purchase of Instantiations.

Among other features, it provides a [graphic display of the dependencies among projects, packages or types](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/codepro/doc/features/dependencies/dependencies.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [SonarJ](http://www.hello2morrow.com/products/sonarj) or the [Sotograph](https://www.hello2morrow.com/products/sotograph) to analyze and visualize the dependencies in your code base. However, it seems to be a commercial product and I'm not sure about their licensing policies but at least at a first glance it looks like a powerful tool.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse has some build in capabilities like the caller hierarchy  or type hierarchy (F4).

But for reverse engineering your better done with good plugins. 
Some UML Plugins allow to reverse engineer java code. Example is ObjectAID, ModelGoon, many commercial ones... Best place to find some is on Eclipse Marketplace searching after UML...
Eventually you will like [Javadoc as UML](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/javadoc-uml-view), too.

Good luck in your project!